# Plotting a function while varying a variable (on the x-axis) using two formulas

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, trigonometry, code-request

I want to plot the following function, where `Rb` is the variable (that has to be on the x-axis):

```
y[Rb]:=2*fin*(2*T*Ud - ((Ud)/(fin)) + ((Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T])/(2*Pi*fin)) + 
   c*Rb*(2*Ud - Uin)*(Exp[-((T)/(c*Rb))] - 1))
```

Now `Ud`,`fin`, `Uin` and `c`are constants, for example

```
Ud = 0.7, fin = 50, Uin = 5,  c = 470*10^(-6)
```

But to find `T` I need to solve:

```
FindRoot[
 Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud == (Uin - 2*Ud)*Exp[-T/(c*Rb)]
 , {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)}
 , WorkingPrecision -> 20
 ]
```

Now how can I plot the function `y[Rb]` while varying `Rb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

Define Constants:

```
Ud = 7/10; fin = 50; Uin = 5; c = 470*10^(-6);
```

Define T as a function of Rb. Call it tr[Rb]

```
tr[Rb_?NumericQ] := 
 T /. FindRoot[
   Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud == (Uin - 2*Ud)*
     Exp[-T/(c*Rb)], {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Define y[Rb] with tr[Rb] instead of T

```
y[Rb_] := 
 2*fin*(2*tr[Rb]*
     Ud - ((Ud)/(fin)) + ((Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*tr[Rb]])/(2*Pi*fin)) + 
    c*Rb*(2*Ud - Uin)*(Exp[-((tr[Rb])/(c*Rb))] - 1))
```

Plot y[Rb]. Notice that you get WorkingPrecision warnings. This has to be looked into to see where the precision is getting lost.

```
Plot[y[Rb], {Rb, 1, 10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could solve for Rb

```
RbT = Solve[Abs[Uin*Sin[2*Pi*fin*T - (Pi/2)]] - 2*Ud == (Uin -2*Ud)*Exp[-T/(c*Rb)], Rb][[1]]
ParametricPlot[{Rb, y[Rb]} /. RbT, {T, 1/(4*fin), 1/(2*fin)},AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Unfortunately the Plot is empty, probably because RbT is complex!

Comment: T follows from the equation I stated

Comment: You gave  some values for T in the FindRoot command. These values I used in the ParametricPlot...

Comment: What range `Rb` you expect?